# How to make View controller active with swift?

Tags: iphone, ios9, xcode7, swift2

I'd like to keep the main view controller active when I leave it to another view controller, please I need you help.

What should I do, I'm using Swift programming language.

Comment: What is the purpose for keeping main view controller active ?

Comment: @Hasya I'm using "Apple bonjour" when I leave the main view controller to another view  the socket is already created; but when I come back again to main view controller it fail to create that socket, I want to keep it active even when I leave to another view, so no need to create socket again! 

Comment: So basically a purpose is to keep alive a socket, right ?

Answer (score 0):

Create global class like below with shared instance and method for socket

```
class GLOBAL : NSObject {

    //sharedInstance
    static let sharedInstance = GLOBAL()

     func SocketMethod(){

        // Here is your code for connection , send data and receive data

     }

}
```

Now after login or at main view controller use below

```
GLOBAL.sharedInstance.SocketMethod()
```

This will keep your SocketMethod alive through out app, until you fire close for web socket.

This worked for me, hope this will help you. best luck.